# Resize background image problems on chrome

Tags: jquery, html, css

So im currently developing this site:

http://remedia-solutions.com/clientes/0039_kiplingmexico/demo2/

its almost done but im currently having some problems when the 2 background image resize. On firefox it works perfectly but not in chrome the 2nd background (text background) totally shorten in a wrong way im using only ccs to do this so heres my ccs code for it:

```
#fondo1{
    background-image: url("images/imagesbackground/BACKGROUND-INICIO.jpg");
    background-attachment:  fixed;
    background-position:    top center; 
    background-repeat:      no-repeat;
    background-size:            cover;
    -moz-background-size:       cover;
    -webkit-background-size:    cover;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%; 
}
#fondo1int{
    background-image: url("images/INICIO.png");
    background-attachment:  fixed;
    background-position:    center center; 
    background-repeat:      no-repeat;
    background-size:            50%;
    -moz-background-size:       50%;
    -webkit-background-size:    50%;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%; 
}
```

im using on the 2nd div 50% cause otherwise it will be like hella big.Btw im using parallax but as far as i know it doesnt affect at all.

Heres the image on chrome :

http://oi47.tinypic.com/2ivle8i.jpg

Image on firefox:

http://oi47.tinypic.com/2hr1o9e.jpg

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't really get your problem... Maybe I'm missing something, but I checked in FF and Chrome. What version of chrome are you testing in?

Comment: Hmmm... it should work exactly like FF? Would it be too difficult to make a fiddle? it's kinda hard to see the problems like this

Comment: try resizing the window on chrome and you will see the problem on the  text background! ill work on a fiddle. You will see the background(text) will shrink in a wrong way

Comment: i added some images to show you the problem in chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `-webkit-background-size: 50%;` from your `#fondo1int` in your `.css` and it should behave the same in both browsers.

At the end the class should look like this:

```
#fondo1int {
   background-image: url("images/INICIO.png");
   background-attachment: fixed;
   background-position: center center;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: 50%;
   -moz-background-size: 50%;
   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Awesome tnx! it worked. but i have a doubt where can i found the webkit background size documentation . In other words why does webkit behave is like that?

Comment: You're welcome, yes, there is a place, http://www.webkit.org/projects/documentation/index.html, also complement that with https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/ and you should be ok!